# create JWT using RS256 on APIM AZURE

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I would like to create the JWT using RS256 in APIM Azure. I have the private key, payload and header. all these three needs to be created as one JWT. Is it possible in APIM? any leads or directions would be helpful.

Thanks,
Senthil.U

Comment: Did you check the documentation of APIM Azure? What does it say? Did you try anything yourself? Remember that StackOverflow is not a place where people will write code for you, or look for resources for you. If you have any concrete problem with the process we'll be more than glad to help you.

Comment: I tried out multiple options and Checked out Azure documentation but APIM accept only few classes. so options are very limited and new to this as well so trying out if there is some options available. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please refer the similar SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050233/how-to-validate-jwt-signed-with-rs256-algorithm-with-validate-jwt-policy-in-azur ,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041625/azure-api-management-validatejwt-with-rs256-privatekey , And this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT) .